# Change layout of div on small screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I have a page 2-column layout with the following:

[image]

I need this to become a 1-column layout on mobile:

Top: Yellow (Sidebar Content1) FULL WIDTH

Middle: Green (CONTENT GOES HERE) FULL WIDTH

Bottom: Pink (Sidebar Content2) FULL WIDTH

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.left-sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.left-sidebar #left-sidebar_top {
  height: 500px;
}

.left-sidebar #left-sidebar_bottom {
  height: 400px;
  background: pink;
}

.right-content {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <div id="left-sidebar_top">Sidebar Content1</div>
    <div id="left-sidebar_bottom">Sidebar Content2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-content">
    CONTENT GOES HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this purely with media queries in css? (without changing the html)

If not possible, how would you modify the html structure and css?

EDIT: clarified the question.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this in pure CSS using `@media` queries :)

Comment: @NamKim: well your wording "full width" translates to "100%" or "100vw". using the mentioned media query, just append the media query with the same css witihn again, and fix these new values with what you said: full with etc. setting containers display value from flex to display within the mediaquery does most of it - create a jsfiddle with your example for people to help you. DO NOT expect people to write the complete code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to change the HTML structure: Just delete the wrapper for the left-side elements and use the CSS below. The main thing there is the use of `flex-wrap`, a fixed/limited height for the container in desktop mode (for `flex-wrap` to work) and the `order` parameters for the child elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 902px;
}

#left-sidebar_top {
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  order: 1;
}

#left-sidebar_bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: pink;
  order: 2;
}

.right-content {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 900px;
  background: lightgreen;
  order: 3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    overflow: visible;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: auto;
  }
  #left-sidebar_top {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  #left-sidebar_bottom {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }
  .right-content {
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left-sidebar_top">Sidebar Content1</div>
  <div id="left-sidebar_bottom">Sidebar Content2</div>
  <div class="right-content">
    CONTENT GOES HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was hoping a css-only solution was possible without modifying HTML structure, but I guess it is not, as I suspected.
Thank you for the detailed answer! the flex `order` property is pretty nifty

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the @media to do so?

you can try something like

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px){ //this should cover all the small screens
//write the logic of how you want your various div to change
}
```

Comment: Yes I know what media queries are, but I am looking for the specific css styles to apply to achieve my desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid-layouts for different queries:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

But be aware, old browsers seem to have problems with it (Im looking at you Microsoft).

The grid lets you design your layout like this:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
}
```